# Codeigniter redirect all routes in a group

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

How do I redirect all routes in a group to another route

That is, both
`example.com/group/route` should redirect to `example.com/en/group/route`

`example.com/group/route2` should redirect to `example.com/en/groupe/route2` and so on

Comment: do you really want to redirect to groupe? or is this a typo?

Comment: @Vickel no its not a typo